# Web scrapping using BeautifulSoup if there is a Load More Data Button

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to click "Load More Data" button and then parse using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: No, you need something that interprets and runs the javascript on the page, a headless browser. BeautifulSoup generally cannot do that.

Comment: Which library can you suggest to perform this clicking and then web scrapping from updated page?

Answer (score 0):

"Clicking" an element would be done by doing a request to whatever the url is that the button is linked to. If you open your browser's Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR and click that button you should be able to see if any backend network requests happen that you could mimic in your script.

To "click" something physically would require automating a browser like you can do with Selenium.

Comment: After "clicking" button is done it stays on the same link, just more data is loaded. I was wondering if there is a way to tell Beautiful Soup to see all loaded data of the page.